# Using "cells.find" in a Loop

Tags: excel, while-loop, find, vba

I have two columns. One in Sheet 1 with Names (ex: United States of America) and the other one with the same names in short (ex: United States). I am trying to match this with a loop and a Find inside but it doesn't work.

```
Sub Help()

Dim ra As Range
Dim a As Integer
a = Len(Range("A2"))

Do
Set ra = Sheets(2).Cells.Find(What:=Left(Range("A2"), a), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

a = a - 1
Loop Until ra <> ""

Sheets(1).Range("B2").Value = ra.Offset(0, 1)

End Sub
```

It comes up with "Run time error 91" Variable not set.
I tried to change the place of the "set" (then I would get other mistakes), to change my loop but I don t get it to work.

Comment: Try `Loop Until not ra is nothing`

Comment: @Xabier I am using xlWhole because I want to find the whole "United States" inside of "United States of America, and not the other way around. You would have been right if my Columns were switched

Comment: @SJR Finally worked, thanks!

Comment: Just note that Range("A2") in your find statement is undefined as to sheet - it simply takes whatever sheet happens to be active. You should really define where it is supposed to be.

Comment: Use the example on the [Official Range.Find Method (Excel) page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel)